# How to change default table theme in drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am currently in the process of working on a client management module.
However, with the iPress theme we have chosen, we have display problems (the theme table must be bugged).

[image: Actual render]

Is it possible to change the theme that will take the default table formatting, and not the theme installed?
Eg template.php or that of drupal by default.

Cheers

My module.module:

```
    <?php
function gestion_menu() {
    $items ['joueur/all'] = array (
            'page callback' => 'gestion_joueur',
            'access arguments' => array (
                    'acess content' 
            ),
            'type' => MENU_CALLBACK 
    );
    return $items;
}
function gestion_joueur_sorted() {
    $header = array (
            array (
                    'data' => 'Nom',
                    'field' => 'Nom',
                    'sort' => 'asc' 
            ),
            array (
                    'data' => 'Prenom',
                    'field' => 'Prenom' 
            ),
            array (
                    'data' => 'Poste',
                    'field' => 'Poste' 
            ),
            array (
                    'data' => 'NB',
                    'field' => 'NB' 
            ),
            array (
                    'data' => 'NPD',
                    'field' => 'NPD' 
            ),
            array (
                    'data' => 'Equipe',
                    'field' => 'Equipe' 
            ),
            array (
                    'data' => 'DateDebut',
                    'field' => 'DateDebut' 
            ) 
    )
    ;

    db_set_active ( 'joueur' );
    $query = db_select ( 'joueur', 'j' )->fields ( 'j' );
    $sorter = $query->extend ( 'TableSort' )->orderByHeader ( $header );
    $result = $sorter->execute ();
    db_set_active ();
    return $result->fetchAll ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
}

function gestion_joueur_all() {
    $rows = gestion_joueur_sorted ();
    $header = array (
            array (
                    'data' => 'Nom',
                    'field' => 'Nom',
                    'sort' => 'asc' 
            ),
            array (
                    'data' => 'Prenom',
                    'field' => 'Prenom' 
            ),
            array (
                    'data' => 'Poste',
                    'field' => 'Poste' 
            ),
            array (
                    'data' => 'NB',
                    'field' => 'NB' 
            ),
            array (
                    'data' => 'NPD',
                    'field' => 'NPD' 
            ),
            array (
                    'data' => 'Equipe',
                    'field' => 'Equipe' 
            ),
            array (
                    'data' => 'DateDebut',
                    'field' => 'DateDebut' 
            ) 
    );
    $page_array = array (
            'titre' => array(
                    '#markup' => 'Liste des joueur du club'
            ),
            'tableau' => array(
                    '#theme' => 'table',
                    '#header' => $header,
                    '#rows' => $rows
            )
    );
    return $page_array;
}

function gestion_joueur(){
    db_set_active('joueur');
    $sql = "SELECT Nom,Prenom,Poste,NB,NPD,Equipe,DateDebut FROM joueur";
    $stmt = db_query($sql);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDo::FETCH_ASSOC);
    db_set_active();
    return array(
            **'#theme'=> 'table',**
            '#header' => array_keys($result[0]),
            '#rows'=>$result
    );
    ;
}
```